# libgdx custom file to pixmap/texture

Tags: libgdx, textures, pixmap

I would like to write my own binary graphic format, but now I'm wondering how to set width and height to my pixmap and then set specific pixel to specific color. Does anyone know how to achieve this? I just want to write my own pixmap/texture loader for my custom extension.

Comment: Initialize your pixmap with a width and height `Pixmap pixMap = new Pixmap(width, height, null);`. Then draw a pixel with a color `pixMap.drawPixel(x, y, Color.RED.toIntBits());`

Comment: I've tried with draw Pixel but it seems to be much slower than loading from png file. What is the secret behind libgdx default loader? Can I send somehow my bytes array to pixmap?

Comment: I have no idea, it's a whole different question. It probably uses lower language OpenGL code for this. You should go to the #libgdx IRC chat to find out. But why do you need your own loader?

Comment: Imagine one big texture atlas with more than 30 000 textures and all these textures are in your memory! Instead of this you can create your custom format which will be store this 30 000 texture in one file and loading them while it is necessary.

Comment: Use a `AssetManager` to load and unload things as necessary.

Comment: I'm using AssetManger :),.My problem is behind storing my textures in one binary file.

Comment: Why would you want to store them in one binary file at all? And then custom separate them again makes no sense at all? With `AtlasRegion` you can split larger images. I am 99% sure you don't need to write a custom loader for your problem.

Comment: This file also contains shaders, text files and information about objects. The second reason: file is much smaller than separate files. And finally I can protect my assets :)

Comment: You can do all these things with separate files except for the file size but that is minimal. Besides that readability > filesize. I have no clue why you want to create one huge blob file with all kinds of data.

Comment: Here is a FileHandle to encrypt your stuff: https://gist.github.com/MobiDevelop/6389767 and this FileHandle can be used to have only one file for all your assets (aka archive): https://gist.github.com/MobiDevelop/5514357, it's compressed so probably somewhat smaller as well. No need for a special loader for that, just provide a FileHandleResolver: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#i-only-supply-strings-where-does-the-assetmanager-load-the-assets-from

Comment: I think that @Menno is right - you are trying to reimplement mechanism that you already have in a way that you do not need to achieve something that probably won't work

Comment: @Xoppa
That is the best way :). No I can store my whole data in just one file :)

Comment: @m.antkowicz
Imagine one png file: 960000 x 960000 xd